# How can I implement custom code to be called from an email?

Tags: email, parse-platform

I am using a **custom Parse server** hosted on **Heroku**.

My overall goal is for a unique `PFUser` to be created through someone clicking a button or a activation link in an **email**.

I have figured out how to send emails using Send Grid, however I have no idea how to make a custom button or link in the email that will execute some *unique code*.

**My ideal work flow is:**

- User inputs **unique** `username` and `password` then clicks sign up
- An email is sent to the users email with a button or a link
- Once they click the button or link, somehow **unique code is executed** which signs up a new `PFUser` using the `username` and `password` that the user originally inputed.

I know how to do the first two steps, but have no idea how to execute the unique code from an email.

How is executing unique code from an email usually done? I have read something about `tokens` being used?

Could someone please outline for me how this process works and where I can go to learn all about executing unique code from emails?

Thanks, I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is never executed from email because it is a severe security risk.

To implement something like you're describing, you would send an email to the new user with a unique link to a web page like http://yoursite.com/confirmation/?id=some_unique_id_like_a_UUID

Then on you write the web page (at http://yoursite.com/confirmation/) to read that `id` value and then do the action that "signs up a new `PFUser` using the `username` and `password` that the user originally inputed."